# Center aligning table elements in a custom table

Tags: tables, align, center

```
        \begin{table} \centering
        \caption{Greek Alphabets}
        \vspace{2mm}
        \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{14pt}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
        {\rowcolors{3}{black!30!white!20}{black!10!white!10}
        \begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm} p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm}| }
            \hline
            Capital & Lower-case & Greek & English \\
            \hline
            A & $\alpha$ & Alpha & a \\
            B & $\beta$ & Beta & b \\
            $\Gamma$ & $\gamma$ & Gamma & g \\
            $\Delta$ & $\delta$ & Delta & d \\
            E & $\epsilon , \varepsilon$ & Epsilon & e \\
            Z & $\zeta$ & Zeta & z \\
            H & $\eta$ & Eta & h \\
            $\Theta$ & $\theta , \vartheta$ & Theta & th \\
            I & $\iota$ & Iota & i \\
            K & $\kappa , \varkappa$ & Kappa & k \\
            $\Lambda$ & $\lambda$ & Lambda & l \\
            M & $\mu$ & Mu & m \\
            N & $\nu$ & Nu & n \\
            $\Xi$ & $\xi$ & Xi & x \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Test} \\
            \hline
            $\Pi$ & $\pi , \varpi$ & Pi & p \\
            P & $\rho$ & Rho & r \\
            $\Sigma$ & $\sigma , \varsigma$ & Sigma & s \\
            T & $\tau$ & Tau & t \\
            $\Upsilon$ & $\upsilon$ & Upsilon & u \\
            $\Phi$ & $\phi , \varphi$ & Phi & ph \\
            X & $\chi$ & Chi & ch \\
            $\Psi$ & $\psi$ & Psi & ps \\
            $\Omega$ & $\omega$ & Omega & o \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
```

Above is the code to a table I've made and the result is below. I've tried some answers on here and in the documentation but nothing seems to work, how can I center align all the elements in the table? The multicolumn with "Test" seems to work fine with `{c}`, but this doesn't work in the `\begin{tabular}`.

[image: Result of the LaTeX code above]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Replace  `p{2cm}` with`wc{2cm}` (and load `array` if you didn't).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer mate! It solved the problem.